# Typing hints for complex class hierarchy

Tags: python, oop, generics, abstract-class, type-hinting

Say, you have the following abstract classes with some interfaces defined

```py
import collections.abc
import typing

from abc import abstractmethod


class IterableAbstract(collections.abc.Iterable):
    @abstractmethod
    def some_method_1(self):
        ...

    @abstractmethod
    def some_method_2(self):
        ...

class SequenceAbstract(Abstract1, collections.abc.Sequence):
    ...
```

and classes `BetterIterable` (that inherits `IterableAbstract`) and `BetterSequence` (that inherits `SequenceAbstract`) that implement all abstract functions.

Is it possible to create some class hierarchy for static type checker so that it would be possible to distinguish `IterableAbstract` and `SequenceAbstract` instances with type hints?

To clarify, I am trying to make it possible to write this:

```py
T = typing.TypeVar('T')

def convert_to_sequence(iterable: IterableHint[T]) -> SequenceHint[T]:
    ...
```

I tried to do the following

```py
class IterableHint(typing.Iterable):
    pass

class SequenceHint(Abstract1Hint, typing.Sequence):
    pass

IterableHint.register(BetterIterable)
SequenceHint.register(BetterSequence)
```

but the first viability test gave me an error

```py
>>> IterableHint[int]
TypeError: <class '__main__.IterableHint'> is not a generic class
```

Comment: I'm not following, why don't you use `IterableAbstract` and `SequenceAbstract` as the hint? so `def convert_to_sequence(iterable: IterableAbstract[T]) -> SequenceAbstract[T]:`?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, in this case, it is not possible to specify template parameters as we can do using `typing.Iterable[T]`, for example. `IterableAbstract[T]` will result in `TypeError: 'ABCMeta' object is not subscriptable`

Comment: Ah, of course, you should use `typing.Iterable` and `typing.Sequence` as your base class for your abstract classes instead of the versions available in `collections.abc`, these are generic

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, do you think that it is a good practice? Not for nothing that we have a division into `collections.abc` and `typing`.

Comment: yes, that is what they are created for, it's even documented as such, e.g. [typing.Sequence](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Sequence) is simply "A generic version of collections.abc.Sequence". The separation is an unfortunate consequence of the fact that type-hints came much later.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, thank you very much! It seems work.